# Using Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

When using **Fragments** in Android I can call **fragment elements** as following one.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyProduct>> orderAdap = InvocieProductFragment.mapOrderd;
```

In this case does it creates a new **instance**. Or else is it passing a copy or is it using the same **resource**. When I update a value on such an item does it updates in all places.  I'm somewhat excited on this matter and can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working on regular object instances. There's no magic involved. So you have to propagate changes yourself.

Comment: so each time I'm creating a new instance and they must be changed separately ????

Comment: Yes. Use Broadcasts to propagate changes in your app. I send a local broadcast on changes and pull the new data from my data source (webservice, database, whatever.)